# Visual Studio for Mac not showing C# intellisense for newly added nuget packages

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio for Mac (version: 17.6.9; build: 415) and installed a couple of NuGet packages. But when I try to add those packages inside my C# code, the IntelliSense not showing the package. Please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

I found this issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/intellisense-of-nuget-packages-is-broken/319486) which shows that this same issue was reported earlier and was fixed but I am still facing the issue.

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

**Update 13-Mar-2024**
I checked VSCode as well as per [Peter's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13268855/peter-csala) suggestion, same issue happening. Adding a couple of more screenshots to highlight the issue.

[image: C# dev kit extension is installed in VSCode]

[image: Packages added, but not showing in the intellisense]

**Update 15-Mar-2024**
I tried installing a different package, Moq. Initially, VSCode was not showing intellisense for it. When I restart VSCode, it is showing some. But still not showing for AWSSDK. Please see the screenshots below.

[image: Initially not showing intellisense for Moq package]

[image: After restarting VSCode, showing some intellisense for Moq package]

Comment: A couple of weeks ago (or even month ago) MS announced that they will [discontinue to support VS for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/what-happened-to-vs-for-mac?view=vsmac-2022) at the end of August this year. The suggestion is to use Visual Studio Code with C# Dev Kit on macOS. So, do not expect too much patches for this VS variant.

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala according to your suggestion, I have checked the same code in VSCode and getting the same issue. Please refer to the updated section of the question. I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Do you observe the same behaviour for any other nuget packages or just against AWS ones?

Comment: Hi @PeterCsala I tried adding Moq package and after restart, vscode is showing some intellisense for it. However, still not showing anything for AWSSDK except AWSSDK.Runtime

Comment: My apologies. Found the issue. Even though the .net packages were added like this `dotnet add package AWSSDK.Lambda`, when trying to use inside `.cs` files, the reference should be like this `using Amazon.Lambda` instead of `using AWSSDK.Lambda`. More details here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/quick-start-s3-1-cross.html#s3-1-cross-code

Comment: Nice catch, post it as an answer, not just as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

** Posting it here as an "answer" as per Peter's suggestion. **

Even though the .net packages were added like this `dotnet add package AWSSDK.Lambda`, when trying to use them inside .cs files, the reference should be like this `using Amazon.Lambda` instead of `using AWSSDK.Lambda`. More details here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/quick-start-s3-1-cross.html#s3-1-cross-code